# Crawl with scrapy - error

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am pretty new at Python and webscraping. I want to use scrapy. I am following the official tutorial. I have created a project, but I type 
`scrapy crawl quotes`
An error comes out:
`Unknown command: crawl` 
What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you didn't set Anaconda to be the default python version on your system when you installed it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, what do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crawl` is one of scrapy's subcommands that must be executed from inside a project.
If you attempt to run it while you're not inside one, you get that error.

The error message does seem misleading, suggesting that the command doesn't exist, but if you take a look at how the command line interface is generated in [cmdline.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/cmdline.py#L28), you will see that that is technically correct.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have tried to use the command ``scrapy crawl quotes`` at different levels of the directory. But still it is not working and giving me: ``Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\USER\python.exe C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\scrapy-script.py '``

Comment: Indeed it seems the ``scrapy`` command works only in the ``\Scripts`` directory

Comment: In that case, it seems like an anaconda issue. Unfortunately I know next to nothing about anaconda, so I can't help with that part.